# Отдельные иконки для файлов rar, tar, bz2, gz в Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, иконки

Нашел красивый пак иконок для архивов всех типов, так как стандартная иконка 7-zip на всех архивах просто убивает глаза.

Сначала пытался использовать "7-Zip Theme Manager" (www.7ztm.de), заменились все иконки кроме этих 4х из названия вопроса. "Default Programs Editor" (defaultprogramseditor.com) тоже особо ничем не помог. Правда я не пытался создать новый тип файлов, а пытался привязать к уже существующим типам (7-zip.gz, 7-zip.rar итд).

Потом нашел [File Types Manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) и даже в нем увидел такую надпись: "Notice - Changing the properties of this file type may affect the following extensions: .bz2, .gz, .rar, .tar".

И действительно, при изменении иконок через последнюю программу для любого из типа файлов (.gz, .rar, .bz2, .gz) иконка меняется сразу для всех четверых типов. И объединяет их что-то типа названия "GZ File".

Понимаю, что иконки файлов наверное самая бесполезная вещь, но пока пытался их настроить это уже стало делом принципа. Плюс их ведь добавляют в пак иконок, значит как-то их все-таки можно настроить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все-таки у меня получилось это сделать. Решение оказалось довольно неочевидным.

Для начала пишем в поиске: "Программы по умолчанию".
Потом нажимаем "Сопоставление типов файлов или протоколов с конкретными программами".

В открывшемся окне ищем каждый из этих четырех типов файлов, нажимаем "Изменить программу..." (Или просто кликаем дважды на строку) и снова задаем наш 7 zip в качестве программы. При этом windows видимо как-то заново создает расширение файла и все проблемы пропадают.

Не уверен, что это нужно, но перед этим я еще воспользовался программой "Default Programs Editor" и удалил предыдущие типы расширений, после чего называться расширения стали правильно и перестали зависеть друг от друга, но это по сути ничего не изменило.

И да, я понимаю, что эта проблема возникла только у меня, вероятно из-за программ, которые я ставил на свою систему. Подозреваю, что тут виноват WinRar, но в этом я не уверен.